# Current, proper way to count upper case characters in a string in haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I'm looking to accomplish the same thing as the following function, but since it requires the Haskell 98 module, I don't think I can make use of it on the lab machine.

```
length (filter (isUpper) "SomE RanDOm STRing")
```

I know this is a simple question, but google-fu is not yielding much, thanks.

Comment: The [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) search engine is a good way to find where methods live. Ie searching for [isUpper in hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=isUpper) shows that the function resides in `Data.Char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you do:

```
import Data.Char
```

It looks like the isUpper function is in there now.

Comment: Yep, it's in `Data.Char` now. To figure out where standard library functions like this are, you can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).